# solve $\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x\partial y}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I need to solve $$\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x\partial y}=0$$ with the boundary conditions: $u(x,y=x^3)=\sin(x^6)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y=x^3)=0$.

I got a particular solution, I thing which is $u_p=A\sin(y^2)$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}$, that satisfies the two boundary conditions, but it is rather a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate wrt to $x$ to get that

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = z(y)$$

Integrate wrt to $x$

$$u = \int z(y)dy + g(x) = f(y) + g(x)$$
for two functions $f,g$.

Now add the boundary conditions to find

$$u(x, x^3) = f(x^3 ) + g(x) = \sin x^6$$
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (x,x^3) = g'(x) = 0 \implies g(x) = B \in \mathbb R$

hence $f(x^3) = \sin x^6 - B \implies f(y) = \sin y^2 - B$

which in turn makes $u(x,y) = \sin y^2$

Notice that the coefficient in front of $\sin y^2$ must be $1$ because of the boundary conditions,so your solution is valid only for $A=1$